# Program runs without error but not giving desired output

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-express

Following program extracts data from SQL Server 2008 tables, applies a simple for loop and counts total number of records. Program compiles and runs successfully without any error but doesn't print the total count of records to the screen. It doesn't print anything.
.cs (code behind) is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
namespace CountDocs
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void btnCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=PIMS; Integrated Security=true;");
           {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    String sql = "select * from dbo.Company";
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    con1.Open();
                    Int32 Total = 0;
                            Total = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
                            Console.WriteLine(Total);
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        string companyname;
                        companyname = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                        SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=PIMS; Integrated Security=true;");
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
                            {
                                String sql1 = "select Count(*) from dbo.Documents where Src=" + "'" + companyname + "'";
                                cmd1.Connection = con1;
                                cmd1.CommandText = sql1;
                                con.Open();
                                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                                Int32 Total = 0;
                                Total = (Int32)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
                                Console.WriteLine(Total);
                                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                                {
                                    con.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since program is not throwing any syntax error, I guess it could be a logical error. Could someone please notice it for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use cmd1.ExecuteScalar. no point of using  SqlDataAdapter. ExecuteScalar - Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.

Comment: @Seminda do you think SqlDataAdapter is causing issue?

Comment: No. but if you only need one column then ExecuteScalar is there for you. it will make your code more simple and you can identify your problem very easily.

Answer (score 1):

The system works correct, because if you write **dt1.Rows[0].ToString()** you did not get the value of the cell. That is because System.Data.DataRowSystem.Data.DataRowSystem.Data.DataRowSystem.Data.DataRowSystem does not override the method **ToString()**.

I think you have to use `dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[3]` or `dt1.Rows[0]["column name"].ToString();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: My eye just caught an error. Second connection inside for loop (`con1`) must be opened and closed rather than the first connection(`con`) which is outside the for loop. Did so, now system runs successfully without producing any output.

Comment: What is not working? Do you have some more information? With no comments your code is hard to read...

Comment: With `dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString()` code is throwing error: `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` `dt1` has no column names, so don't know how I should use your second suggestion (`dt1.Rows[0]["column name"].ToString`). Thanks

Comment: Just finished updating and uploading code. Please review. Thanks

Comment: Of course you get an Index was outsite the bounds of the array exception, because you have to replace the 0 and 3 with the values you need... That was only an example...

Comment: only increment used within for loop is `i` and `dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[i].ToString()` generates `Index outside bounds` error. Thanks